# Variable input 208V-600V AC to 24V DC without transformer

Tags: battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, ac-dc

The Question:

How can I design a circuit for an automatic transfer switch that accepts 120V-600VAC and keeps some 24V batteries charged (long term trickle charge is fine). P.S. I would like to keep the whole circuit automatic if I can.

My Research:

Right now I am thinking that I can use a full bridge rectifier and a 1000V Cap to supply a buck converter and filter the output to get a nice 24V DC. I can design a simple buck converter but it seems like other purchasable designs only range from 120-400V and they all seem to stay away from 600V unless they are specially designed for 340-800V but that doesn't meet my range. I am concerned that I might not have the experience to design a safe and efficient circuit for this voltage range.

Final request:

Can anyone recommend some circuitry that I can look into to help me design my circuit? Or if there are safety concerns with a circuit like this can you let me know in case I haven't thought of it.

Edit: Changed capacitor voltage because 600V rms has a peak voltage of 848.5V.

Comment: What kind of current/power do you need?

Comment: Why avoid a transformer?

Comment: You need isolation for safety reasons.  You don't necessarily need a 50/60 Hz transformer, a smaller high-frequency transformer could work as part of a SMPS.  However, none of this is trivial, and a successful design of this type of circuit will require someone with lots of power electronics experience.

Comment: @LordTeddy I would need to supply at least 500mA but If i could do like 5-10A it would be a lot better.

Comment: @Andyaka I have two reasons for wanting to avoid transformers. 1. they need to be hooked up differently depending on the input voltage. meaning that someone has to go and physically turn a knob.
2. I might be wrong about this but usually high voltage transformers are huge, heavy and expensive. I want to keep this as light and cheap as possible.

Comment: @JohnD an SMPS is pretty much exactly what i am trying to design. I am an electronics engineering technologist, but I have never worked with 600V ac before so i am looking for resources to help make this possible.

Comment: The peak voltage of 600 VAC is 848 V.  You need a capacitor rated higher than that, and a buck converter that can handle that kind of voltage.

Comment: Those are both null and void reasons. You are thinking of old 50/60 Hz transformers when in fact modern converters use a tiny transformer and a switching frequency of circa 100 kHz. These transformers can be driven in a "variable" way thus, you have a wide input voltage range in which the output is stable.

Comment: @Andyaka can you give me a keyword so I can lookup one of these circuits. Because yes I am trying to replace a transformer that is made for 60hz conversions.

Comment: @SimonB you are correct I realized my mistake a bit after i posted this. i will update my question. I am however considering designing a buck converter for this. I am also looking to see if there are any better options though.

Comment: 600VAC distribution is normally a Y with central point connected to ground.. That means that you will get 347VAC between phase and ground.